# DTM Extraction/Smoothing in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, elevation

I have an .las file, intended to be a DTM (bare earth) that I generated from a photogrammetry software package that has come out just a bit too lumpy. I now have the license for that software tied up for a long time on the next one, and am looking for tools to smooth out this DTM in ArcGIS. I have harnessed my education as best as I could, from generating a meaned grid with LAS to Raster to using Focal Mean and Focal Minimum, generating a raster to contours and back to raster.

It seems that no matter what I do, how large I make the search area or grid spacing, I can't get rid of the lumps. The area I'm working on is very mountainous, and I believe that to be part of the problem.

[image]

Does anyone have any really good tips or tools that might help me out here? I have access to an ArcGIS 10.2 advanced license, Spatial Analyst and 3D Analyst. I also have access to Global Mapper.

Comment: you could try resampling your raster to a larger cell size which may help remove some of your unwanted lumps, probably not the best method though


http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000009t000000


i'd recommend selecting cubic as the resampling technique

Comment: the generalization toolset might also help you...

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000033000000.htm

Comment: I've been working with that also. The problem I have there is that the resampling will either exaggerate the lumpiness or will completely blow away the mountains and flatten everything out. It may just be a matter of heuristics and I need to just find the right parameters.

Comment: Also, you might find you get a better initial DTM if you avoid LAS to Raster tool and instead convert your LAS to point features and then use an interpolation method such as spline. Just an idea (seeing as you have access to 3D analyst)

Comment: it sounds like you've used just about every method and are still coming up short. Some data is just too bad to fix, like the silk purse/sows ear. **Did you filter the classes in the LAS file** or did you use all of them?

Comment: Have you tried making a LAS Dataset and manipulating it using the LAS Toolbar built into 10.2? It helps you classify data - you can view by cross section, etc. You could then subset to the points you want - There's a pretty robust LAS Dataset to TIN tool.